# parse.com API: Is it possible to send multiple push notifications in one network call?

Tags: parse-platform, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I am looking at the Parse Push API documentation and have tried it successfully, but is it possible to send multiple push notifications in one network call, for example by sending a JSON array of notifications.

Single notification JSON object as in the official documentation:

```
{
        "where": {
          "injuryReports": true
        },
        "data": {
          "alert": "Willie Hayes injured by own pop fly."
        }
      }
```

I would like to send multiple notifications using an array instead:

```
[{
        "where": {
          "injuryReports": true
        },
        "data": {
          "alert": "Willie Hayes injured by own pop fly 1."
        }
      },
  {
        "where": {
          "injuryReports": false
        },
        "data": {
          "alert": "Willie Hayes was not injured by own pop fly 2."
        }
      } 
]
```

An array of notifications does not seem to be supported at this time. I am getting an invalid JSON format error in the response. I was wondering if this is supported, but I am using the wrong JSON structure.
If it is not supported, I would request the parse team to support it as it will be very convenient for processing multiple notifications with one API call instead of making a separate network call for each push.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can push a `JsonArray` from `parse notifications` via `bundle`.

If your Activity is launched via a push, then the `bundle.getIntent().getExtras()` will have the JSON in the extra string `com.parse.Data`.

For more details, please refer to [here](https://parse.com/questions/how-do-i-get-the-json-from-a-push-notification-in-android-when-the-activity-is-opened-by-clicking-on-the-notification) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26828411/bundle-of-type-java-lang-string-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonarray).

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer my question. My use case is sending a push from a server through the REST API. I want to be able to send multiple push notifications (with each having its own "data" and "where" query), so that if I have say, 10 notifications to push (which may go to different recipients), I can send them to parse.com using one api/network call instead of 10. Looks like at this time, the "push" resource accepts only notification based on what I have tried.

Comment: I am not very sure if the this is supported, I think you can head to [here](https://parse.com/help) to get some help.